# Rails 3.2 Asset Precompile is skipping files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, assets

## Stack

- Ruby 1.9.3
- Rails 3.2.12

## Issue

We have precompilation issues with our application.

We're trying to remove `config.server_static_files = true` and `config.assets.compile = true` from our production configs, but are constantly missing assets whenever we precompiled. Even though these assets live in `app/assets`, while other files in the same directory are seen and compiled.

Ex:

```
app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
app/assets/stylesheets/some_slider_lib.css
app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css
```

After precompiling

```
public/assets/application-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.css
public/assets/some_slider_lib-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.css
```

And the `manifest.yml` is also missing the bootstrap file among other assets.

Same thing with our `vendor` folder.

## Attempts

The following is the only way that I've managed to precompiles everything.

```
config.assets.precompile += ["*.css", "*.scss", "*.js", "*.coffee"]
```

However, this feels like overkill. I thought all files within the asset pipeline would be compiled. Is this not what is suppose to happen?

Also tried `rake assets:precompile --trace`, but this was unhelpful.

If anyone could provide a little guidance, suggestions or more it would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: and your application.css file - does it contain all the css and scss files you want compiled?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is an existing project where the decision was made not to include all files within `application.css`, instead they are requiring assets per page. Obviously not ideal, but unrelated to the asset compilation into `public/assets` as far as I can tell.

Comment: it's not unrelated.  the application.css is a manifest.  it's what tells the precompiler which assets need to be included in compilation.  It does make sense if you want a tighter per-page setup - but for those assets you MUST whitelist and while it feels clunky, it is actually the way it works.

Comment: Then how would you explain 75% of the assets precompiling with absolutely no `require_tree .` or `require bootstrap` within application.css. If this were the case, then wouldn't nothing be precompile not even application.css? I will try your suggestion, but I'm not convinced.